# how to reinstall your network and make your Ip static?

Tags: networking

My problem is that I ruined my network driver or something like that .
I simply `sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces` and edit the file like

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

I didn't change netmask and broadcast.

After that I issued the command `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`.

Then Ubuntu crashed. It didn't show a thing only a terminal that's not responding.
I restarted the system and there wasn't a sign that he could possibly connect to the Internet.
Please help me. How I can make my Ubuntu 12.10 HP laptop and make the IP address a static IP address?

Comment: Please, can you specify what kind of Ubuntu distribution you are using.

Comment: @martin I installed ubuntu 12.10 and didn't change much or istn't that not what you're meaning

Answer (score 1):

The default content of `/etc/network/interfaces` is

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

If you removed those lines I imagine the lack of a loopback network might well do bad things to linux.

You can configure a static IP using the `NetworkManager` GUI (Network Icon->Network Settings->(Connection)->IPv4 Settings). If you want to do it manually, the syntax you describe appears correct (see `man interfaces` for more details).

Typically on a small network it is easier to set up a static IP by leaving the computer to use DHCP and configuring the router to assign a specific IP address based on the computer's MAC address (which the router will probably tell you, and if not can be found with `ifconfig` ("HWaddr") or `lshw -c network` ("serial")).